# Put another hdd in ubuntu server 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, mount

I am using Ubuntu server 10 for LAMP and hosting sites.

I installed the server without a GUI, and what I want to do is to add a second HDD for some backup.

I attached the HDD but the problem is I don't know now how to mount it without a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

- Use [fdisk](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk) to partition the drive.
- use [mkfs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs) to create a filesystem.
- use [mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) to mount it.

Comment: could you please answer to absolute dumb beginer how do i do that.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis: The OP doesn't even need to do that I provided links to each of the man pages ;)

Comment: Oh, you did too :) I shall retract my comment!

Answer (score 1):

1. dmesg | grep sd[a,b,c,d,e] or dmesg | grep hd[a,b,c,d,e]
   90% it will be sdb or hdb
2. you  need to make file ssystem on it, `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb` for example or use xfs
3. mkdir /backup; mount /dev/sdb /backup
4. `df -h`
5. add your new drive to /etc/fstab in order to automount:
   blkid | grep /dev/sdb or /dev/hdb
   and add the following line to /etc/fstab

> ```
> # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
> UUID=80d1d2d5-610d-48ce-8263-c749252eca66   /backup xfs   defaults    0    0
> ```

done

:~$ dmesg | grep sd[a,b,c,d,e]

[    0.873576] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    6.645849] EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    6.645853] EXT4-fs (sda1): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    8.853977] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
[    8.859269] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   21.446754] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to see which device is the hard drive you have connected. 
You can do that with the following command:

```
# fdisk -l
```

I don't know how many disks you have or how your disks are divided.

I suppose you have a disk with two partitions.
Maybe you'll see something like this in result of fdisk -l command:

```
/dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2.
```

If you connect an another disk, you will see a /dev/sdbX the result of fdisk -l command.
If this disk is empty, you can use the "cfdisk"  to format and make a new partition.
Click [here](http://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Cfdisk_Basic_Partitioning_Scenarios) to learn how use "cfdisk"

At the end, use the mount command to  manage the data on your disk.

Example:

```
 # mkdir /mnt/mydisk (create a folder to access the data on your disk)
 # mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/mydisk
```

Regards.